# Why does my unity project have a huge blue edge after building it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, screen

I have a project in unity and i want to build it to give it to a friend.

When i try the project in the editor, verything seems to be working fine and you can play the game. After building however, it looks like this
[image: Screenshot]
Please help!

Comment: because the default background is blue and you're not filling it

Comment: Have you tried to set the game view to your screens resolution?

Comment: It's set to 1920x1080

Answer (score 1):

Resolution difference. Probably your editors game view is set to "free aspect" and if your screen is like 1080p (1920x1080) that window might be 1000x600(for example) and you made things that fills 1000x600 but if your friends screen is 1920x1080 he would see that extra space you did not fill. But the main problem here is not that. If you wanna make something like UI that will fill the whole screen you should make it on top of the canvas and make it flexible.[image: the free aspect I mentioned]

If it works on your computer and not on your friends then it might be that you have 1080p 1920x1080 whilst he has 4k 3840x2160

Comment: I already have a canvas, but could you explain what you mean with flexible?